# Difference between "Cry" and "Weep"?

Tags: word-usage

From what I understand, **Cry** is used when somebody's tears come of their eyes and the sound is loud.

I hate when Babies **cry** for no reason.(Baby=cry not weep, Right? )

And **Weep** is used when somebody cries but silently. For eg.

I saw her **weeping** while watching a sad movie.

But instead of *"I saw her **weeping**"* I hear *"I saw her **crying**"* when she was actualy weeping(crying silently).

Is my usage correct? If not correct me Please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ***To weep*** is [a relatively literary / dated / poetic usage today.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+was+weeping%2Cshe+was+crying&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20was%20weeping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20was%20crying%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshe%20was%20weeping%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20was%20crying%3B%2Cc0) I suggest you just stick with ***to cry*** for all contexts. But you might note that if they're gonna ***weep*** at all today, people (not babies) normally only do so in  ***sorrow***, not pain / discomfort.

Answer (score 2):

Really, **cry** is make a loud noise, including shouting, wailing.  But it can also used when tears come, with or without noise, and certainly the normal way to say it.  **Weeping** is means there are tears, normally of sadness, normally without sound.  "Weeping" is also used for any slow leaking of liquid, such as from a wound, or a rotten vegetable

Such as:

- The baby cried all night and we got no sleep
- The widow cried but you could hardly hear her

Some relatively uncommon uses:

- There was **weeping and wailing** after his football team lost = tears + noise
- **Silently crying** in the corner = tears
- A **battle cry** = something you shout when you go into battle
- **Cry** “God for Harry, England, and Saint George!” -- very well known Shakespeare, Henry V = imperative shout